# USB CDC Communication-Device Waiting for second command from host for sending response for first command

Tags: arm, embedded, usb, atmel, cdc

I'm working using atmel studio 7.0, the code which i'm using is USB  **Communication Device Class (CDC)  for ATSAMD21**.  My application is to read the command  from the host to the device and perform the operation suggested by the host and send  acknowledgement back to the host from device.

- Java GUI we are writing into MCU USB,we will receive data into MCU using **udi_cdc_read_buf()** call and received data we are sending back to the JAVA host as a acknowledgement using **udi_cdc_write_buf()** .
- 1.Device Waiting for second Command from host for sending response for first Command.

1st Command from host---->No acknowledgement received from device to host

2nd Command from host---->Host received  acknowledgement for 1st Command .

3rd Command from host----->Host received  acknowledgement 2nd Command.

- Here if i debug the code i can see the data "3434" in the buffer. Device send the data to host only when another data is received from the host.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
    int write_data(uint8_t *msg){
    uint8_t buffer[4]="3434";
    udi_cdc_write_buf(buffer,4);
    return (SUCCESS);
  }
```

--->How this is happening in USB Communication? i'm stuck with this any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't possible to reproduce for anyone else, so your best bet is to follow the data. Fire up the oscilloscope and figure out what's going on.

Comment: hi  Lundin , Is there any reasons can you suggest for this issue?

Comment: Could be anything. Incorrect configured port on either side, mixed up USB lines, missing signal ground, wrong baudrate, broken IC, poor soldering etc etc.

Comment: This is probably caused by poorly designed interaction between your MCU program logic and the MCU side of the USB interface.  But with none of the detail of that included in the body of your question, this is unanswerable.

Comment: To determine when the data is sent, you can implement a transmit-complete callback. In the `conf_usb.h` file there is a definition for `UDI_CDC_TX_EMPTY_NOTIFY`. Implement a callback function and use it in that definition. If the callback happens soon after `udi_cdc_write_buf` is called, then the problem is with the Java app. If it is not called until the next data is received, then it's probably the MCU code.

Comment: hi  D Krueger,  I implemented UDI_CDC_TX_EMPTY_NOTIFY,this callback is not coming everytime,that is why data is not transferring everytime,what would be the issue?how can I solve

Comment: Is the first callback occurring after the second command is sent? (p.s. You should use @ when replying to a comment so the person gets notified.)